# Use an array passed by express in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, pug

I have this Javascript function in my `index.pug` file:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
 $(document).ready(function() {
    let chart = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
    let lineChart = chart[0].chart;
    let pieChart = chart[1].chart;
    
    //TODO: Import Backend Features for usage (Banquery).
    // chart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 20000;

    lineChart.update();
    pieChart.update();
 })
```

And in `server.js` (An express app) this code to give an array of months:

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {
    month: month
  });
});
```

My question is: How can i interact with this month array in the pug file for usage?

Comment: If you have access to the var where you call pug, just pass it into a template with `pug.compile()` or `pug.render()`: https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818326/symlink) for giving me the link to the Getting Started Page i fixed my code:

```
let month = [#{month}];
```

with this i was able to get my array to work in the frontend. :)